# How to add string array into chartcontrol series

Tags: c#, .net, charts, devexpress, datasource

I have these arrays:

```
string[] Line1= data[3].ToString().Split(' ');
string[] Line2= data[4].ToString().Split(' ');
```

The string array contain only integer values. Data are like `-20 -30 -12 0 10 20 30` and so on.

Now want to add these values which is in `lineNeg1` to Devexpress Chart Control Series without loop.

As right now things are working but due to loop, system gets too slow. Code sample is here under:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < Line1.Length; i++)
        {
            int y = int.Parse(Line1[i]);
            SeriesPoint pt = new SeriesPoint(i, y);
            chartControl1.Series[0].Points.Add(pt);
        }
```

Is there any way that i can do something like: `Add string array to series without using loop`

maybe like: `series[0].addrange[Line1]` <- `Maybe this kind of something option is available`

I know the state is wrong, still just want to give an idea of what i am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq:

```
int[] ints = Line1.Select(x => int.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

It's still a for-loop, but now it's hidden! The compiler needs to convert the strings into ints one by one as they're fundamentally different things and stored quite differently. Strings are objects whereas integers are native types. It's not like Javascript or PHP where strings and integers get converted on the fly unfortunately. So this doesn't help you much, it's just semantic sugar.

Now, as far as adding the series goes, maybe the problem is that the chart redraws every time a point is added. Have you tried your code like this:

```
chartControl1.SuspendLayout();
for (int i = 0; i < Line1.Length; i++)
    {
        int y = int.Parse(Line1[i]);
        SeriesPoint pt = new SeriesPoint(i, y);
        chartControl1.Series[0].Points.Add(pt);
    }
chartControl1.ResumeLayout();
```